# Scroll does not work in fixed and absolute positions

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

The scroll doesn't work on fixed and absolute positions and I don't know what else to add

```
.modal-overlay {
  z-index:9999;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgba(77, 77, 77, .7);
  transition: all .4s;
  width:100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.modal-backgroundparent {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.modal-background {
  z-index:10000;
  width: 350px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

HTML Template from Modal

```
<div class='modal-overlay'>
 <div class='modal-backgroundparent'>
  <div class='modal-background'>
   <img src="img/images.png">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is the result of the code above that I made and it can't scroll automatically in the modal-overlay section
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOyDc.png)

Comment: You can either add a runnable code snippet or provide a link on codepen, etc. So that it will be easier to reproduce this issue and guide you better.

Answer (score 0):

The "modal-background" does not need to be positionned "fixed" as the parent already is.